# QtQuick is not installed properly with Visual C++

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qml, qt-quick, openvr

We are trying to run OpenVR emulator (link https://github.com/matzman666/OpenVR-InputEmulator) in visual studio 2015. The build is successful. But we are getting the error

[image]

It seems that Qt library is not installed properly in our machine. We have tried reinstalling Qt library. The log below says that QtQuick is not installed. However, we have fully installed Qt 5.7.0 . Can anyone please provide some clue or help regarding this ??

[image]

Comment: I assume it could not find QtQuick library files. First, copy QtQuick debug libraries into the folder where your executable file stays and try running. Second thing, I think it should work in release mode, as the error says "Debug error". Could you try these two?

Comment: Yes, i have tried both of them.. but no luck. as you said i have build it in release mode still getting the same error. and also tried to copy the qtquick bin folder to directory where app stay but still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean bin folder or its contents (like `Qt5QuickControls2d.dll`, `Qt5Quickd.dll`, etc.)?

Comment: i mean its content like Qt5Quick.dll Qt5Qml.dll Qt5Core.dll etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in your path I see you have the bin dir and the root qt dir, you need to have the lib dir as well. And you can delete the root dir, nothing will need that.

So add:

c:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015_64\lib

Then it might help too to add:

QTDIR=c:\qt\qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015

Not to the PATH but to the var QTDIR. That may or may not be necessary at all though, but it could help

Comment: Another way - is to configure `qt.conf` file properly